# spigot recognizes my command when I type it but when I press enter nothing happens

Tags: java, minecraft

so yeah it's pretty self explanatory when I type the command it recognizes it but does nothing, here is everything I have related to this command:

onCommand method:

```
    public boolean onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String label, String[] args) {
        if(cmd.getName().equals("hello")) {
            if(sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player)sender;
                player.sendMessage("elo " + player.getName() + " your computer has virus");
            }
            else {
                sender.sendMessage("CONSOLE!!!! GET OUTTA HERE BOT!!!!");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: firstPlugin
 
version: 1.0
 
api-version: 1.16
 
main: com.roey.firstplugin.Main
 
commands:
  hello:
    aliases: []
    description: elo
```

I have Java experience but no spigot experience

Comment: hey do I did some extra things to try and see the problem and I think my on command method is never actually called

Comment: nvm arguments were in the wrong order

Comment: So it's fixed now?